# Logging unhandled exception independent of user interaction

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF C# application where I log unhandled exceptions to a file. So inside the MainWindow.xaml.cs I define a event handler as follows:

```
public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
//...
this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
}
```

and then I log the exception as follows:

```
    void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {                
     myLogger.log(myLogPath, e.Exception.ToString(), e.Exception.StackTrace, Logger.LogLevel.Error);           
    }
```

And when such exception occurs, .NET pops up the following message box:

[image]

The thing is if one clicks Continue and then waits some seconds the exception is logged.  But if one exits the message box without continue the exception is not logged.

I want the exception to be logged even the user doesn't click Continue. Is there a workaround for this or at least to force the message box to chose Continue automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Handled` property of the `DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs` to `true`, do the logging and then exit the application:

```
void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    myLogger.log(myLogPath, e.Exception.ToString(), e.Exception.StackTrace, Logger.LogLevel.Error);

    MessageBox.Show("Error...", "caption...", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    Current.Shutdown();
}
```

You should also display your custom error message. The general .NET error dialog isn't very helpful or nice to display to the user.